# Why does NHibernate require an Oracle stored procedure to return a result set?

Tags: nhibernate

Why does NHibernate require an Oracle stored procedure to return a result set?  It seems like this requirement adds overhead to open a data reader when it is not necessary.

Comment: Are you looking for a scalar result from an Oracle stored procedure?  Can you please provide sample code to clarify what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate does not require stored procedures at all. In fact, they are discouraged.

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html